# graph - The implementation of updating Minimum Spanning Tree after adding a new edge

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Here is an excise

> Suppose we are given the minimum spanning tree T of a given graph G
>   (with n vertices and m edges) and a new edge e = (u, v) of weight w
>   that we will add to G. Give an efficient algorithm to find the minimum
>   spanning tree of the graph G + e. **Your algorithm should run in O(n)
>   time to receive full credit.**

I have this idea:

`In the MST, just find out the path between u and v. Then find the edge (along the path) with maximum weight; if the maximum weight is bigger than w, then remove that edge from the MST and add the new edge to the MST.`

---

The tricky part is how to do this in O(n) time and it is also I get stuck.

The question is that how the MST is stored. In normal Prim's algorithm, the MST is stored as a parent array, i.e., each element is the parent of the according vertex.

So suppose the excise give me a parent array indicating the MST, how can I release the above algorithm in O(n)?

First, how can I identify the path between u and v from the parent array? I can have two ancestor arrays for u and v, then check on the common ancestor, then I can get the path, although in backwards. I think for this part, to find the common ancestor, at least I have to do it in O(n^2), right?

Then, we have the path. But we still need to find the weight of each edge along the path. Since I suppose the graph will use adjacency-list for Prim's algorithm, we have to do O(m) (m is the number of edges) to locate each weight of the edge.

...

So I don't see it is possible to do the algorithm in O(n). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you have is right. Note that, finding the path between `u` and `v` is `O(n)`. I'll assume you have a `parent array` identifying the MST. tracking the path (for max edge) from `u` to `v` or `u` to `root vertex` should take only `O(n)`. If you reach `root vertex`, just track the path from `v` to `u` or `root vertex`.

Now that you have the path from `u -> u1 ... -> max_path_vert1 -> max_path_vert2 -> ... -> v`, remove the edge `max_path_vert1->max_path_vert2` (assuming this is greater than the added edge) and reverse the parents for `u->...->max_path_vert1` and mark `parent[u] = v`.

Edit: More explanation for clarity

Note that, in MST there will be exactly one path between any pair of vertices. So, if you can trace from `u->y` and `v->y`, you have only traced through atmost `n` vertices. If you traced more than `n` vertices that means you visited a vertex twice, which will not happen in an MST. Ok, now hopefully you're convinced it's O(n) to track from `u->y` and `v->y`. Once you have these paths, you have established a path from `u->v`. Do you see how? I'm assuming this is an undirected graph, since finding MST for directed graph is a different concept in itself. For undirected graph, when you have a path from `x->y` you have a path from `y-x`. So, `u->y->v` exist. You don't even need to trace back from `y->v`, since weights for `v->y` will be same as that of `y->v`. Just find the edge with the maximum weight when you trace from `u->y` and `v->y`.

Now for finding edge weights in O(1); how are you storing your current weights? Adjacency list or adjacency matrix? For O(1) access, store it the way parent vertex array is stored. So, `weight[v] = weight(v, parent[v])`. So, you'll have O(1) access. Hope this helps.

Comment: If I use parent array for the MST, I don't think tracking the path between u and v is O(n). For example, if u is not v's ancestor, and v is not u's ancestor, instead, u and v has a common ancestor y, you can trace from u to y and from v to y, how come you can trace from u to v or v to u in O(n)?

Comment: And also, from the parent array how can you get the weight of each edge in O(1)?

Comment: @JacksonTale Edited my answer for more details answering your questions. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Well - your solution is correct.

But regarding implementation, I dont see why you are using G instead of T to find the path between u and v. Using any search traversal in T for the path between u and v, will give you O(n). - That is, you can assume that v is the root and performs a Depth-First Search algorithm [in this case, you will have to assume all neighbors of v as children] - and stop the DFS once you find u - then, the nodes in the stack corresponds to the path between u and v.

It is easy afterward to find the cost of each edge in the path (O(n)), and it is easy as well to delete/add edges. In total O(n).

Does that help somehow ?

Or maybe you are getting O(n^2) - according to my understanding - because you access the children of a vertex v in T in O(n) -- Here, you have to present your data structure as a mapped array so that the cost is reduced to O(1). [for instace, {a,b,c,u,w}(vertices) -> {0,1,2,3,4}(indices of vertices).

Comment: I think finding the path between u and v will cost more time if the MST is given as a parent array.

Comment: I dont really know what you mean by parent array honestly, but in algorithms, if you dont have a suitable data structure then dont expect to get a good performance always.

Comment: Would you please explain how your tree is stored (in details) - i may fnid the exact way of doing it if possible